# Why is the [testmigrations] tag blacklisted in Stack Overflow Teams?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams, tag-blocklist

I recetly discovered the [testmigrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testmigrations) tag is blacklisted in SO Teams.
It is not blacklisted on Stack Overflow.
Is it a bug or feature?

---

[image: SO Teams [testmigrations] is not allowed]

---

[image: Not blacklisted on SO Main]

---

[image: Blacklist image]
 (obtained at https://stackoverflow.com/c/{team name hee}/admin/blacklist)

Comment: Ha, good catch. That's the default row used in our base schema for Teams... Digging into the code has exposed a couple of bugs that we're addressing now!

Comment: Fix is in review, will be deployed on Monday

Comment: @DeanWard It is monday, why the blacklist is the same?

Comment: @smileycreations15 it's not Tuesday yet.

Comment: @Stijn It says "Fix is in review, will be deployed on **monday**", not tuesday

Comment: Let me rephrase: it's still Monday.

Comment: @DeanWard Still not fixe in monday...

Comment: @smileycreations15 no you’re right, it’s not fixed there were more pressing issues at hand today. It’ll be deployed at some point this week. Patience is a virtue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch! Each team has a schema in our SQL database and when it is initially created we run a sequence of baseline SQL to make sure everything is ready for use. One of those baseline SQL scripts contained a row of data in the `Blacklists` table which we use on the public sites to stop people posting spam and other nasty things.

We've removed this blacklist across all teams and fixed a couple of other bugs which would have made blacklists act strangely in Teams. Should be all set now.